# matplotlib.sankey: Is it possible to change/set the individual *gap* between branches for a sankey diagram

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Does anyone know if it is possible in matplotlib.sankey to have individual *gap* sizes (matplotlib.sankey.gap) between different arrows for a subplot? i.e. difference values for *gap* within a single matplotlib.sankey.add instance?

Website for reference:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/sankey_api.html?highlight=sankey%20finish#matplotlib.sankey.Sankey.add

Thanks